# Umount error with device busy, now device name locked from use

Tags: linux, centos

I had issues unmounting a device, it kept saying device was busy. lsof and fuser showed no device was attached.

I have managed to umount device with the -l option. However, when I plug the hard drive it has incremented to the next device up. e.g. from /dev/sdc1 to /dev/sdd1.

How can I find what's preventing /dev/sdc from being used again? Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason you have not tried rebooting?

Comment: It's in a production environment and so I do not want to reboot it. If the problem does occur again, I would like to be able to able to fix the problem and not reboot each time it happens. A work around has been to mount it using label instead.

Comment: You aren't supposed to use the `/dev/sd**` devices normally anyway; you should be using UUIDs or labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're *certain* that the block device is no longer in use (including no longer being present in LVM, etc), you can remove it from the scsi subsystem.

```
_disk=sdc
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/$_disk
print 1 > /sys/block/$_disk/device/delete
```

consider whether `sdd` should go as well.  from your description, it sounds like it should

then plug in the drive and perform a scsi bus scan again

```
for i in `ls -d /sys/class/scsi_host/host*`
do
  echo "- - -" > ${i}/scan
done
```

and hopefully it'll come back as `sdc`.

this works well and i've removed disks like this in production (albiet under change control), but always take responsibility and put it through your test environments first, if possible

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you backup the data on the drive as quickly as possible. It's not a good sign when a drive is behaving as you describe. After that I would try the drive in any other machine, that way you can be sure that the hard drive is not the problem. Maybe even try another drive in the same machine. A reboot should leave the device /dev/sdc free.